# Are there infinitely many integer-valued polynomials dominated by $1.9^n$ on all of $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The original post is below. Question 1 was solved in the negative by David Speyer, and the title has now been changed to reflect Question 2, which turned out to be the more difficult one. A bounty of 100 is offered for a complete solution.

**Original post.** It follows from the prime number theorem and the periodicity properties $f(n+p) \equiv f(n) \mod{p}$ that for each $A < e$ there are only finitely many integer polynomials $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $|f(n)| < A^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is an integer-*valued* polynomial in $n$ bounded by $2^n$.

*Question 1.* Are there infinitely many integer polynomials with $|f(n)| < e^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

*Question 2.* Given $A < 2$, are there only finitely many integer-valued polynomials $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $|f(n)| < A^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: For any fixed $k$, $n^k < e^n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large - say, larger than $m$.  It follows that $f_k(n) := n^k - m^k$ is smaller than $e^n$ for every $n$ and $k$.  Unless I'm making a groggy mistake...

Comment: It is not smaller in absolute value, though. Your polynomial has $|f_k(1)| = m^k - 1 > e$.

Comment: Oops!  Groggy mistake indeed...

Comment: It's probably worth noting here the fact that any integer-valued polynomial is an integral linear combination of the polynomials $\binom{x}{k}$.

Comment: Indeed, and perhaps the title should now be changed to: "Are there infinitely many integer-valued polynomials dominated by $1.9^n$ on all of $\mathbb{N}$?"

Comment: Regarding question 2: when $k$ is sufficiently large we can't take $f(x)=\binom{x}k$, since $\binom{2k}k$ is asymptotic to $2^{2k}/\sqrt{\pi k}$ as $k\to\infty$.  In general if $f(x)$ is integer-valued of degree $k$, with $k$ sufficiently large, then the inequalities $|f(n)|<A^n$ with $n$ near $2k$ will impose huge constraints on $f$.  Maybe somehow one can use them to show that there are no $f$'s of suff.large degree?

Comment: Also, there are only finitely many integer-valued $f$'s of any fixed degree $k$ which satisfy $|f(n)|<2^n$ for all $n$, since if we write $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i \binom{x}i$ with $a_i\in\mathbf{Z}$ then $|f(0)|<2^0$ bounds $|a_0|$, after which $|f(1)|<2^1$ bounds $|a_1|$, and so on.  So Question 2 is really asking whether there exist $f$'s of arbitrarily large degree.

Comment: Hm, does this mean I should somehow donate half of the 200-point bounty to David Speyer?  I suppose I can achieve this purpose by posting a new question "What's the optimal $A$?", putting a 100-point bounty on it, and accepting David's answer which would be basically a link or pointer here...

Comment: Well, actually, *he* would have to donate it to you - for I already awarded you the old 100 bounty. Then I intended to set a new 100 bounty for him, but it turned out this wasn't an option, so I went for 200. (The latter hasn't yet been awarded, so if I award it to you instead, what you say could be an option if you set a 150-point bounty, if that's possible, for his answer :).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  I'm entirely fine with David getting
double my bounty, since his answer is definitive
(besides being a double answer - both an upper and a lower bound
which "happen" to coincide!).

Comment: Looking beyond Mathoverflow, is it worth writing this up for
publication as a joint paper?

Comment: @ Noam Elkies: I think so; the relation to Fekete's theorem which you and David discovered seems particularly interesting to me. My contribution here, though, is minimal and reduces to having merely asked the question.

Comment: Here is a generalization of Ruzsa's conjecture which, though not involving polynomial coefficients anymore, is nonetheless in the spirit of the two questions. It is suggested to me by the connection with Fekete's theorem (and by that of Polya-Carlson-Bertrandias). Let $G \ni 0$ be a pointed (say) simply connected domain, and $\rho$ its conformal mapping radius. Let $h : P \to \mathbb{N}_0 \cup \{\infty\}$ be a function on the set $P$ of primes, and consider the set $S(G,h)$ of those $f \in \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ which are meromorphic on $G$ and whose reduction $f \mod{p}$ at each prime $p$ (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) is a rational fraction of degree $\leq h_p$. Then: 1) If $\log{\rho} + \liminf_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p : h_p < n} \log{p} > 0$, the set $S(G,h)$ should only contain rational functions in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$. 2) If however the inequality in 1) is not satisfied, the set $S(G,h)$ should be uncountable.

Comment: (cont.) This generalizes in an obvious way to global fields and to algebraic curves of higher genus. It would thus be a sharp algebraicity criterion, of which I can only prove a weaker version involving an inequality stronger than 1). It was this type of problems which motivated me to ask question 1.

Comment: @Vesselin Dimitrov: Your contribution is not minimal;
not only is asking a good question valuable in itself,
but you also gave the example showing $A \leq 2$
which suggested that this "Question 2" has quite a different flavor from
"Question 1" on ${\bf Z}[x]$.

Comment: @ Noam Elkies: Thank you! It was of indeed the example of $\binom{n}{k}$ which led me to ask question 2. (Otherwise I was considering rather different kinds of stuff, more in line with the first question.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Question 2:
The constant $A$ can be brought down to $\sqrt 3$, and probably
a bit below that but not all the way down to $1+\epsilon$.

Instead of the polynomial $f(n) = {n \choose m}$, use a
finite difference of such polynomials, 
$$
f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^m (-1)^i {m \choose i} {n \choose m+i}.
$$
This is the $x^n$ coefficient of 
$$
\frac1{1-x} \left( \frac{x(1-2x)}{(1-x)^2} \right)^m
$$
and can be estimated by contour integration on $|x| = 3^{-1/2}$;
the maximum of $|f(n)|^{1/n}$ occurs near $n=3m$, for which
the critical points are at $x = (3 \pm \sqrt{-3}) / 6$.

Note that for $f(n) = {n \choose m}$ the generating function was
$\frac1{1-x} (x/(1-x))^m$, and the maximum occurred near $n=2m$, 
for which the critical point was at $x = 1/2$.
The factor $1-2x$ kills that maximum, and it seems that
using $x/(1-x)$ and $(1-2x)/(1-x)$ to the same power is optimal.
To reduce $A$ further, try to include also some power of $(3x^2-3x+1)/(1-x)^2$
to kill the new critical point.

Comment: So I was wrong on both questions :-). Since you believe the limit infimum [of values of $A$] to be nonetheless strictly $> 1$, interesting what the actual value would be. Regarding integer polynomials the right question would have been: what is the limit infimum $\delta$ of the values of $c > 0$ such that there are infinitely many $f \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ with $|f(n)|/n! < c$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? We know from David Speyer's solution that $\delta \in [1/2,1]$.

Comment: Thanks also to David Speyer for his solution to Question 1. But the bounty was offered for Question 2, so I'm marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Since $25 \geq 2 \cdot 11$ (and $11 \geq 10$)
this also gives David Speyer the rare "Populist" badge, which is his third gold and which David
may actually prefer to the bounty points :-)

Comment: Was there a motivating application for either question?
(It's a natural problem in any case but it would be nice if
the answer has some further use.)

Comment: Not an application, but it came up in relation to an old conjecture of Ruzsa characterizing the subring $\mathbb{Z}[1/(1-x)] \subset \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ by the two properties: 1) radius of convergence (and I would add: meromorphy) is strictly $> 1/e$; and 2) for a set of primes $p$ of full density, the mod $p$ reduction is $A_p(x)/(1-x)^p$, with $A_p$ a polynomial of degree $< p$. Perelli and Zannier have shown that such an $f \in \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ is at least $D$-finite. (continued.)

Comment: (continued.) And a closer look at their argument shows that not only the order of the differential equation can be taken to depend only on the radius of convergence, but that if the coefficients satisfy $|a(n)| < A^n$ for all $n \geq n_0$ and $A < e$, then in fact $f$ satisfies one of a finite set (depending on $A$ and $n_0$) of linear homogeneous differential equations. This implies that the degree of a polynomial in Question 1 is bounded for $A < e$.

Comment: (And I meant, after all, to write $\mathbb{Z}[1/(1-x)] \subset \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ and $f \in \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ in the above comment. Sorry about this, as well as for the switch of notation, $f$ now denoting the generating function.)

Comment: Let me spell out what I think Noam is implying. Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and degree $d$. Let $f_m(n)$ be the coefficient of $x^n$ in $p(x)^m/(1-x)^{dm+1}$. Then $f_m$ is an integer valued polynomial. If $|p(x)/(1-x)^d| \leq 1$ on the circle $|x| = r$, then integrating on this contour gives a bound $|f_m(n)| \leq C r^{-n}$. So our goal is to find polynomials $p$ which can push the radius $r$ as far out as possible.

Comment: This is the opposite of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32961, which aims to find monic polynomials $f$ and $g$ so that $\{ |f(z)|=|g(z)| \}$ stays as close to $0$ as possible.

Comment: The integers $f(n)$, when $n = 3m$ seem to be divisible by all primes between $2m$ and $4m$, which leads to a Chebyshev estimate slightly better than the one from the middle binomial coefficient. I haven't looked at David's new example but this suggests that getting $A$ down to $1$ might involve the PNT.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch It looks like $|f(2n)|$ is $(6n)! (2n)!/((4 n)! (3n)! n!)$, see https://oeis.org/A211419 .

Comment: Question: This constructs a constant $C$ and infinitely many integer values polynomials with $|f_m(n)|<C r^{-n}$. Clearly, at the cost of increasing $r$ infinitesimally, we can find an $N$ so that we get $|f_m(n)| < r^{-n}$ for $n>N$. But how do we guarantee ourselves $|f_m(n)|<r^{-n}$ for all $n$?

Comment: For $m$ large, the average of $|f_m(z)|$ over $|z|=r$ is $o(1)$
because $|f_m|$ behaves like the $m$-th power of a function
that's at most $1$ but attains that value at only finitely many points.
(Most likely $O(m^{-1/2})$ unless for some reason 
$1 - \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} |f_m|^{1/m}$ has a quadruple or
higher-order zero at some point of $|z|=r$.)

Answer (score 55):

$\def\ZZ\mathbb{Z}$Question 1: No. Let $C>1$. I will show that there are only finitely many $f(x)$ in $\ZZ[x]$ so that $|f(n)| \leq C^n$ for all $n \in \ZZ_{\geq 0}$.

Choose $d$ large enough that, for all $k>d$, we have $k! > 2 C^k$. I claim that a polynomial with $|f(n)|<C^n$ is determined by its values on $0$, $1$, ..., $d$. Suppose, to the contrary, that $f(n) \neq g(n)$ but that they agree for $0 \leq n \leq d$. Let $k$ be the first integer where $f$ and $g$ disagree.

So $f(x)-g(x)$ is divisible by $x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-k+1)$, so $f(x) - g(x) = x(x-1) \cdots (x-k+1) h(x)$ for some $h$ with integer coefficients. So $f(k) - g(k) = k! h(k) \equiv 0 \bmod k!$.

But, by assumption, $|f(k)|$ and $|g(k)| < C^k < k!/2$. So it is impossible that $f(k) \neq g(k)$ and $f(k) \equiv g(k) \bmod k!$. This contradiction concludes the proof.

Question 2 is still stumping me.

Comment: Very neat. I had failed to fully exploit the polynomial assumption. My argument for $C < e$ was otherwise similar; it amounted to noting that $f(k)-g(k)$ was divisible by the product of the primes less than $k$. The latter argument works for arbitrary mappings $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with the property $f(n+p) \equiv f(n) \mod{p}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all primes $p$: for $C < e$ there are only finitely many such mappings (conjectured to be polynomials anyway), while for $C = e$ there are uncountably many.

Comment: Thus, you have shown that for each $n_0 < \infty$, there are only finitely many $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $|f(n)| < n!/2$ for all $n \geq n_0$. This is close to optimal upon considering $k!\binom{n}{k}$, although (especially in view of the proof) it could still be an interesting problem to see whether the coefficient $1/2$ of $n!$ is optimal, or if it could be improved to any constant smaller than $1$.

Comment: (To correct my first comment above: I meant to say that for each $C > e$ there are uncountably many such mappings $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ --- not for $C = e$.)

Answer (score 45):

The optimal growth rate is $\tau:= (1+\sqrt{5})/2$. Specifically, for any $\epsilon>0$, there are infinitely many integer valued polynomials bounded by $(\tau+\epsilon)^n$, but only finitely many below $(\tau-\epsilon)^n$. The first part of this answer (written first) proves the finiteness; the second uses Noam Elkies' idea combined with a theorem of Fekete to prove the infinitude.

---

Fix $\epsilon>0$. I will show that there are only finitely many integer values polynomial $f(z)$ with $|f(n)| < (\tau-\epsilon)^n$.

Let $f$ be such a polynomial of degree $d$. Set
$$\frac{p(z)}{(1-z)^{d+1}} = \phi(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) z^n$$
Then $p(z)$ has integer coefficients, $p(1) \neq 0$, and we can uniquely recover $f$ from $p$. Moreover, there is some $M$ and some $\delta_1>0$ (dependent on $\epsilon$) so that $|\phi(z)| < M$ on $|z|=\tau^{-1}+\delta_1$.

We make the change of variables $u = 1/(1-z)$, so $z=1-1/u$. We have $\phi(1-1/u) = p(1-1/u) u^{d+1}$. Set $q(u) = p(1-1/u) u^{d+1}$. From the properties of $p$ above, $q$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $d+1$, and $|q(1/(1-z))| < M$ when $|z|=\tau^{-1}+\delta_1$. The map $z \mapsto 1/(1-z)$ sends $|z|=\tau^{-1}+\delta_1$ to a circle which contains the circle of radius $1+\delta_2$ around $\tau$ (for some $\delta_2>0$).  So, using the maximum modulus principle, $|q(u)|<M$ on  the circle of radius $1+\delta_2$ around $\tau$.

We therefore make one more change of coordinates, $v=u-\tau$ and $s(v) = q(v+\tau)$, to get a polynomial $s$ with $|s(v)|<M$ on the circle of radius $1+\delta_2$ around $0$. Although $s$ does not have integer coefficients, its leading term $v^{d+1}$ is a nonzero integer.

Choose $D_1$ sufficiently large enough that $2 \pi M (1+\delta_2)^{-D_1-1} <1$. Then, for $D_2 \geq D_1$, taking a contour integral around $|v|=1+\delta_2$ shows that the coefficient of $v^{D_2}$ in $s(v)$ has absolute value $<1$. Since the coefficient of $v^{d+1}$ is a nonzero integer, this establishes that $d<D_1$. So we have bounded the degree of $f$. Thus, $f$ is determined by its values at $D_1$ integers, and there are only finitely many possible polynomials $f$.

---

Now for the reverse bound. This argument is closely based on the proof of Fekete's Theorem [here](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0084532.pdf). (The original paper is [here](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01504345.pdf), but I don't speak German so I haven't checked whether they are the same argument.)

Our first goal is to establish the following: Let $r < 1$. There exists a nonzero polynomial $q(u)$ with integer coefficients so that $|q(u)|<1$ on the circle $|u-\tau|<r$.

Choose an integer $T$ large enough that, for any $N > T$, we have
$$r^N + (1/2) r^{N-1} + (1/2) r^{N-2} + \cdots + (1/2) r^{T+1} + (1/2) r^T < 1/3.$$

Take $N$ larger than $T$. Define $q^N_N(u) = (u-\tau)^N$. Define $q^N_i(u)$ to be the unique polynomial of the form
$$q^N_i(u) = q^N_{i+1}(u) + \theta_i \cdot (u-\tau)^{i}$$
so that $|\theta_i| \leq 1/2$ and the coefficient of $u^{i}$ in $q^N_i$ is an integer. Set $q^N(u) = q^N_T(u)$. So the coefficient of $u^k$ in $q^N(u)$ is an integer for $T \leq k \leq N$.
For $u$ on the circle $|u-\tau|=r$, we get
$$|q^N_T(u)| \leq r^N + (1/2) r^{N-1} + \cdots + (1/2) r^T < 1/3.$$

Let $(c^N_{T-1}, C^N_{T-2}, \ldots, c^T_0)$ be the last $T$, noninteger, coefficients of $q^N$. By the Pigeonhole principle, we can find $q^M$ and $q^N$ so that
$$\sum_i |\{ c^N_i - c^M_i \}| r^i < 1/3$$
where $\{ x \}$ is the distance from $x$ to the nearest integer. We define $q(u)$ to be the result of taking $q^N(u) - q^M(u)$ and rounding the last $T$ coefficients to the nearest integer. We have now constructed $q$.

We now undo the above argument. Since $|q(u)|<1$ for $|u-\tau|<r$, we have $|q(1/(1-z))|<1$ on the disc with diameter $(1-(\tau+r)^{-1}, 1-(\tau-r)^{-1})$. This contains the circle of radius $\tau^{-1} - \delta_1$ about $0$, where $\delta_1 \to 0$ as $r \to 1$. So Noam's argument constructs infinitely many polynomials bounded by $(\tau+\delta_2)^n$.

---

Just for the fun of it, I used the above construction to find a polynomial $\sum_{i=1}^{20} \theta_i (u-\tau)^i$ with $|\theta_i| < 1/2$ and all coefficients
other than the constant term integral. The constant term turned out to be $-3878005 + 1739105 \sqrt{5} \approx 10752.00000977$. If I round that off to $10752$, the resulting polynomial factors as $(2 - u)^9 (1 - u)^5 (3 - 3 u + u^2) (7 - 15 u + 14 u^2 - 6 u^3 + u^4)$. Making the variable substitution suggests that our next family of polynomials should be the coefficients of
$$\frac{1}{1-z} \left( \frac{z^5 (1 - 2 z)^9 (1 - 3 z + 3 z^2) (1 - 5 z + 11 z^2 - 13 z^3 + 7 z^4)}{(1 - z)^{20}} \right)^m.$$
Of the four roots of $7 - 15 u + 14 u^2 - 6 u^3 + u^4$, two are at distance $0.883514$ from $\tau$ and two are at distance $1.02472$. Much past $N=20$, my naive implementation times out.

Comment: The best exponent $k$ in $z^k(1-2z)^k (1-3z+z^2)  / (1-z)^{2+2k}$
is not $k=2$ but $k \approx 3.7559$ [it doesn't have to be rational;
just use $z^A (1-2z)^A (1-3z+z^2)^B / (1-z)^{2A+2B}$ with $A/B \rightarrow k$].
This gives a bound about $1.68053$, which is the largest root of
$x^8 - 7x^6 + 23x^4 - 49x^2 + 49$.  One can do better yet by
using different multiplicities for the factors $z$ and $1-2z$,
which brings the bound down to about $1.656246$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks! In the comment above, should $z^2-3z+1$ read $3 z^2 - 3z +1$?

Comment: You're welcome, and yes I meant $1-3z+3z^2$, not $1-3z+z^2$.  
(And I was wondering if it might be converging to $\tau$...)

Comment: So this is a special case of the general problem: Find an integer polynomial which takes values of norm $\leq 1$ on a circle of radius $r<1$ around a real point $x$ in the complex plane. (With $r=A/(A^2-1)$ and $x=A^2/(A^2-1)$) Since it doesn't seem like we are dealing with especially easy $x$, I don't think this will converge to $\tau$ unless the problem is solvable for all $r$ and $x$. But if it were, this would probably be in the literature David Speyer surveyed...

Comment: @WillSawin Check the update, this problem is solvable for all $r$ and $x$. Fekete's result is that, if $h(x)$ is a monic polynomial with real coefficients, then we can find a a monic polynomial with integer coefficients which is $<1$ on $\{ z: |h(z)|<r \}$. Or, at least, I think that's what the result unpacks to, and I wrote out the argument above for the circle to see if I got it right.

Comment: A generalization of Fekete's theorem inspired by arithmetic geometry (and, I think, in a particularly illuminating way) appears in Chinburg's paper "Capacity theory on varieties": http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1991__80_1/CM_1991__80_1_75_0/CM_1991__80_1_75_0.pdf See Theorem 1.2 and the Minkowski application in the paragraph following it.

Comment: In any case, this is amazing. Now I have to award the bounty. Since the solution is a joint one, here is what I will do. I will award the current bounty to Noam Elkies' answer, and start a new bounty of the same worth to reward this complete answer.

Comment: A bounty of 200 will be awarded to this answer in 24 hours. (It turns out that 1) one may not set two bounties of the same worth on the same question, and 2) one has to wait for 24 hours before the bounty can be awarded.)

Comment: Do you know if there are finitely many integer-valued $f$ such that $f(n) \leq \tau^n$?

Comment: I don't know. My vague guess would be no, because the recipe for constructing polynomials below $(\tau+\epsilon)^n$ has so many "large but finite" error terms that I feel like you shouldn't be able to squeeze all the way down to $\tau^n$. But it would certainly be interesting to know!

Comment: Neat computation.  The factor $P_4=1-5z+11z^2-13z^3+7z^4$ is the minimal
polynomial of the critical points I found for the optimal
$z^k(1-2z)^k (1-3z+3z^2) / (1-z)^{2+2k}$.  The exponents $5,9,1,1$
for $z$, $1-2z$, $1-3z+3z^2$, and $P_4$ must be just an approximation
to the optimal proportion: even without $P_4$ the optimal ratio
is not rational.  There's no need to stop at $N=20$: tell **gp** 
**tau=(sqrt(5)+1)/2; zdif(x)=x-round(x);** 
and then **speyer(N, q) = q=(u-tau)^N; forstep(i=N-1,0,-1, q -= zdif(polcoeff(q,i))*(u-tau)^i); round(q)** will compute well beyond **speyer(20)** ... [cont.]

Comment: [cont.'d] ... before complaining about loss of precision.
For $N \leq 37$ we see only the same four factors,
except for a degree-$11$ irreducible in the $N=30$ polynomial; then there are
some new factors of degree $\geq 5$ for $38 \leq N \leq 50$, and for $N>50$
it more-or-less breaks down, usually giving just a few factors of
$z$, $1-2z$, $1-3z+3z^2$, and sometimes $P_4$, and then a huge residual factor.
The neat exception is $N=64$ where we get a pair of
degree-$13$ irreducibles.  But there might be a tweak that continues
giving good factors past $N=50$ and $P_4$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies So, how do you find the optimal ratio of exponents?

Comment: @Will Sawin: For each $m\leq49$ there is an integer valued polynomial of degree $m$ and $\lvert f(n)\rvert\le\tau^n$ for all non-negative integers $n$. However, this family doesn't work for larger degrees anymore.

Comment: @PeterMueller: Interesting! Which family?

Comment: @Will Sawin: Those polynomials which have generating function $\sum f(n)x^n=\frac{x^{m-k}(2x-1)^{k-2r}(3x^2-3x+1)^r}{(1-x)^{m+1}}$, where $0\le 2r\le k\le m$. For $m\le49$, there are $k$ (around $0.7m$) and a small $r$ such $\lvert f(n)\rvert\le\tau^n$.